# Technology Stack advice for live chat between different domains

Tags: javascript, sockets, websocket, cross-domain

I am working on a pilot project. It’s a web-based chat application (say `abc.com`). I created a chat window (just the basic UI). What I wish now is from this chat window to chat with a customer support person who is on a different domain.

Say for example, there is an e-commerce website `xyz.com` and they have a live chat support available in their website. Is it possible to chat with the support person in `xyz.com` from `abc.com`?

I researched a bit on this and found out this can be accomplished using `WebSocket`s. Can anyone throw some more light on this like whether it is feasible, the technology stack which can be used / researched further for this project etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple demo of a chat application which uses WebSocket take a look at https://demo.crossbar.io/chat/index.html#ch1. This works across domains without a problem since all chat clients connect to a central router which distributes the messages. (Bonus: there are also clients for WAMP, the protocol this uses, for quite a few languages besides JavaScript, making adding components in other languages a breeze - see http://wamp.ws/implementations).